# Spring multiple transaction roll back

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, transactional

I have a requirement wherein I have to insert into 3 separate tables through 3 DAO classes.

```
ClassADAO
ClassBDAO
ClassCDAO
```

I want to have a single transaction for all the three classes so that if one insertion fails I want to roll back the complete transaction that is inserted through previous classes.

I have my configured xml as shown below

```
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
  <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>
  <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
            id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"></property>
    <property name="username" value="******"></property>
    <property name="password" value="********"></property>
  </bean>
```

In controller annotated as follows

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class }, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

But still if **ClassCDAO** fails, I can c insertions in my db from **ClassA** and **ClassB**

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class }, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MyController{

@Autowired
private MyBusinessLayer mybusinessLayer;

@RequestMapping(value = "/register.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveRegistration(
            final @ModelAttribute("registration") @Valid Registration registration,
            final BindingResult result, final Model model) {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "myPage";
            } else {
                mybusinessLayer.saveRegistration(registration);
            }

        return "myPage";
    }

}
```

**My Business Layer:**

```
 @Component
 public class MyBusinessLayer{

    @Autowired
    private ClassA classA;

    @Autowired
    private ClassB classB;

    @Autowired
    private ClassC classC;

    public void saveRegistration(Registration registration) {
        Company company = RegistrationHelper.buildCompany(registration);
        classA.saveCompany(company);
        Contact contact = RegistrationHelper.buildContact(registration, company.getCompanyId());
        classB.saveContact(contact);
        User user = RegistrationHelper.buildUser(registration, contact.getCompanyID(),
                contact.getContactID());
        classC.saveUser(user);
    }    

  }
```

**ClassADAO:**

```
@Component
public class CompanyDAOImpl implements CompanyDAO {

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveCompany(Company company) {
        String insertCompanySQL = //insert statement;
        //code here
        SqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource(bind);
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(insertCompanySQL, paramSource);
    }
}
```

ClassBDAO and ClassCDAO are also as shown above.

Comment: Show all relevant code, please. In this case, the invocations of DAO methods.

Comment: @Nikem : Update the code in my question itself

Answer (score 0):

Move your `@Transactional` annotation to `MyBusinessLayer` class. Unless you have your DataSource configured as `autocommit`, your code seems correct.

Comment: I moved my @ Transactional to business layer but still the Pre insertions are happening and also there is no additional autocommit set to false or tru in my config xml datasource